# box-sizing: border-box;

Tags: html, css

А можно ли верстать, используя полностью в верстке `box-sizing: border-box;`?

К примеру так

```
html { box-sizing: border-box; } , :before, *:after { box-sizing: inherit; }
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

Если честно, то нужно.

Тот же Twitter Bootstrap, как [пример](http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.css):

```
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
     -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Префиксы??? о_О

Comment: Вопрос к разработчикам Twitter Bootstrap ?!?!?!?!??!!!!!?????

Comment: Ну, видимо они всякое старьё пытаются поддерживать... И селекторы не через запятую по той же причине - если `:before, :after` нет, то для `*` всё равно сработает

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему вопрос совместимости. Согласно справке http://htmlbook.ru/css/box-sizing данное свойство соответствует спецификации css3 и поддерживается далеко не всеми старыми браузерами.

Comment: Я сильно удивлюсь, если кто-то всерьёз продолжает верстать под один из указанных по ссылке старых браузеров

Comment: Вы удивитесь, но согласно статистике больше 50% всех, кто пользует ie, сидят на шестой версии и ниже. https://www.artlebedev.ru/tools/browsers/

Comment: «Этот инструмент сдан в архив и больше не поддерживается». Смею сомневаться в достоверности данных заброшенного инструмента, который не в курсе существования версий IE старше шестого, а также не в курсе про Chrome :)

Comment: А вот поддерживаемой статистике по более крупному сайту я склонен доверять больше: http://goo.gl/fmDAuw

Comment: А вообще для подобных вещей существует caniuse.com, согласно которому [box-sizing будет работать у 97% пользователей](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing) (третий коммент подряд, вот я флудер)

Comment: Эти старые никому не сдались... А в IE5.5 вообще border-box по умолчанию идёт. Насчёт IE6 не уверен. IE7 - да, мимо.

Answer (score 0):

```
*, :before, :after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```